# PHP "&" character in $_GET variable issue

Tags: php, url, get

How can I put '&' symbol to URL GET variable so it is part of string?
The problem is it always split the string to next variable.

How can I make this work?

```
localhost/test.php?variable='jeans&shirts'    // so it executes it like a string

<?php

require "connect.php";

$variable = $_GET['variable'];

echo $variable;

?>
```

output is 'jeans'

instead of 'jeans&shirts'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You will want to [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) your string:

```
// Your link would look like this:
'localhost/test.php?variable='.urlencode('jeans&shirts');
```

When you want to use it, you would decode it:

```
echo $variable = urldecode($_GET['variable']);
```

**ENCODE:** http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

**DECODE:** http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

---

**EDIT: To test write this:**

```
echo $url = 'localhost/test.php?variable='.urlencode('jeans&shirts');
echo '<br />';
echo urldecode($url);
```

Your result would be:

```
// Encoded
localhost/test.php?variable=jeans%26shirts
// Decoded
localhost/test.php?variable=jeans&shirts
```

Comment: This is misleading. You need to urlencode the string before using it in the url. Your 1st line of code should not reference `$_GET['variable']` at all, and instead show perhaps a link tag or similar

Comment: @Steve Sorry, I was updating that when you commented because I knew it was a bit misleading

Comment: doesn't work for me :\ but never mind I did workaround by excluding the '&' symbol in URL

Comment: You should always use the `urlencode()` when turning a variable to query string. Should have made the `$_GET['variable']` output to `jeans%26shirts`.

Comment: No problem hopefully you can get it to work! It will save you headaches in the future!